# Direct sum decompositions over rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be one of its nonzero left-ideals. Is it true that $R \cong I \oplus R\big/I$?

Notice that we can consider $R$ to be an left $R$ module and $I$ one of its $R$-submodules. We know from linear algebra that in the special case of $R$ being an field, if we consider any vector space $V$ and any vector subspace $W$, it is true that $V \cong W \oplus V\big/W$. Therefore, we are looking for some generalizations here.

Comment: What happens if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=2\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Suppose $\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus 2\mathbb{Z}$. So, there is an isomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus 2\mathbb{Z}$ which is, in particular, a group isomorphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, in order to know $\phi$ we only need to know its value in $1$. If $\phi(1) = (0, z)$, the value $(1, 1)$ would never be achieved, contradicting the fact that $\phi$ is a bijection. So, we have $\phi(1) = (1, 2z) \Rightarrow \phi(n) = (n%2, 2zn)$. But, in this case, the value $(0, 2z3)$ would not be acheived. Again, a problem with the bijection. Therefore, no isomorphism.Tnx

Answer (score 1):

This splitting of $R$ occurs iff $R/I$ is a projective module, and it is frequently not.

It is also easy to find rings with ideals that aren't direct summands, too. All nontrivial ideals of an integral domain that isn't a field are good examples.